# Equivariant complex $K$-theory of a real representation sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, stable-homotopy, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

Consider the one-point compactification of a $U(n)$-representation $V$, denoted by $S^V$. I want to caclulate $\tilde{K}_\ast^{U(n)}(S^V)$. When $V$ is a complex $U(n)$-representation, we can use the Equivariant Bott periodicity to infer that $\tilde{K}^G_0(S^V)\cong \tilde{K}^G_0(S^0)$. I want to know what happens when $V$ is a real $U(n)$-representation, more specifically, I want to identify the object $\tilde{K}^G_{\ast}(S^{\text{Ad}(U(n))})$, where $\text{Ad}(U(n))$ is the adjoint representation of $U(n)$.

My guess is, if the adjoint action of $U(n)$ is orientable, the Thom isomorphism gives the isomorphism to $K^{U(n)}_\ast(S^{|Ad(U(n))|})$ (?) on the real vector space $\text{Ad}(U(n))$ or the answer will be some twisted from of $\pi_\ast(K)[t,t^{-1}]$, where $t$ is a degree two element.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible approach, which is specific to the adjoint representation.  Let $X$ denote $U(n)$, regarded as a $U(n)$-space by the rule $g.x=gxg^{-1}$.  Put $X_k=\{x\in X:\text{rank}(x-1)\leq k\}$, so we have a $U(n)$-equivariant filtration
$$ \emptyset = X_{-1}\subset 1=X_0 \subset X_1 \subset \dotsb \subset X_n = X $$
Haynes Miller proved that there is a stable splitting $\Sigma^\infty X_+\simeq\bigvee_{i=0}^nX_i/X_{i-1}$, and one can check that this works equivariantly.  For $u\in\mathfrak{u}(n)$ we have the Cayley transform $g=(u+1)(u-1)^{-1}$ which lies in $X_n\setminus X_{n-1}$.  This construction gives a homeomorphism $\mathfrak{u}(n)\simeq X_n\setminus X_{n-1}$, and we can pass to the one-point compactification to get a homeomorphism $S^{\mathfrak{u}(n)}\simeq X_n/X_{n-1}$.  More generally, suppose we have a subspace $V\leq\mathbb{C}^n$ of dimension $k$, and an antihermitian endomorphism $u$ of $V$; this gives an element $g=((u+1)(u-1)^{-1})\oplus 1_{V^\perp}$ lying in $X_k\setminus X_{k-1}$.  If we let $G_k=U(n)/(U(k)\times U(n-k))$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $T$ the tautological bundle over $G_k$, and $\mathfrak{u}(T)$ the associated bundle of antihermitian endomorphisms, and $G_k^{\mathfrak{u}(T)}$ the corresponding Thom space, we find that $X_k/X_{k-1}\simeq G_k^{\mathfrak{u}(T)}$.  Thus, Miller's splitting takes the form
$$ \Sigma^\infty X_+ \simeq \bigvee_{k=0}^n G_k^{\mathfrak{u}(T)}. $$
Thus, the group $K_{U(n)}^*(X)$ splits as a direct sum of pieces, of which the top piece is the group $K_{U(n)}^*(S^{\mathfrak{u}(n)})$ that you asked about, and the other pieces are closely related.

I think that there is literature about $K_{U(n)}^*(X)$ but I do not remember at the moment what it says.  One point is that we can let $I$ be the augmentation ideal in $K_{U(n)}^*(\text{point})=R(U(n))[v,v^{-1}]$ and form the completion $K_{U(n)}^*(X)^\wedge_I$.  The Atiyah-Segal completion theorem identifies this with $K^*(EU(n)\times_{U(n)}X)$.  If I remember correctly we can also identify $EU(n)\times_{U(n)}X$ with the free loop space $LBU(n)=\text{Map}(S^1,BU(n))$.

Comment: If G is a connected compact Lie group whose pi_1 is torsionfree, one can identify K^\*\_G(G) with the algebra of Kahler forms on the (complex) representation ring Rep(G), with \Omega^1 in deg 1. (This is due to Brylinski-Zhang, but it can also be seen using the final observation in your answer + Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg.) Since G = U(n) here, R(U(n)) = Z[x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x_n^{\pm 1}], so the algebra of Kahler forms is obtained by adjoining exterior generators dx_1, ..., dx_n. It seems to me that K_{U(n)}^*(S^ad) is free over R(U(n)) generated by dx_1 ^ ... ^ dx_n.

Comment: Neil, thank you for the explanation. This describes the $U(n)$-equivariant $K$-cohomology. Do you know what would be the recipe for reaching the $U(n)$-equivariant $K$-homology of $S^{\mathfrak{u}(n)}$?

Comment: In general $K^i_G(S^U\wedge Z)=K^{i-2d}_G(Z)$ if $U$ is a complex virtual representation of complex dimension $d$.  Thus, if $V$ is a real representation of real dimension $d$ then $K^G_i(S^V)=K_G^{-i}(S^{-V})=K_G^{-i}(S^{-\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}V+V})=K^{2d-i}_G(S^V)$.

Comment: skd, thank you for your comment. Could you please expand a bit more on what you said? I fail to understand how S^ad kicks into the picture.

Comment: @Shakuntala Sure -- basically, (the unbased suspension spectrum of) S^ad is the top cell of U(n)_+; the decomposition in Strickland's answer above is a much more precise version of this observation. In ordinary cohomology, for instance, if I write H^*(U(n); Z) = {exterior on y_1, ..., y_n}, each basis element in this exterior algebra corresponds to one cell of U(n). From this perspective, the unreduced coh of S^ad is just the summand corresponding to the top-dimensional class, i.e., y_1 ^ ... ^ y_n. These dx_j classes in my comment are the K-theory analogue of these y_j classes.

Comment: In various other contexts, the pieces in the Miller splitting correspond to the individual exterior powers summing up to an exterior algebra.  I assume that @skd is guessing, very plausibly, that it works the same way in the Brylinski-Zhang setting.  If so, then the group $K_{U(n)}^*(S^{\mathfrak{u}(n)})=K_{U(n)}^*(X_n/X_{n-1})$ will just be the top exterior power.